# Google Plus Button Not showing up in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-plus

I know google plus button doesn't work on IE7 but it also not working on IE8 , I can't see any error

here's the sample i am using

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body>

<div style="width: 50%;margin: auto;">

<!-- Place this tag where you want the +1 button to render -->
<g:plusone annotation="inline"></g:plusone>

<!-- Place this render call where appropriate -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you've found a solution yet. 
Here is my solution anyway, hopefully it will work for you too 
[Does Google Plus Button API Support Internet Explorer 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902337/does-google-plus-button-api-support-internet-explorer-8/)