# Does Google Plus Button API Support Internet Explorer 8

Tags: google-plus-one

Does anyone know if the Google Plus Button is supported in IE8? This question suggests that it does not support IE7: [Google +1 Button not working in IE7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6218789/google-1-button-not-working-in-ie7). Additionally, the question links to a page (http://support.google.com/accounts/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1151309) that suggests that IE8 is supported. Interestingly, when I visit that page in Chrome, I get the G+ button, but when I visit it in IE8, I do not.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's one odd-ball version of IE8 (version 8.0.7600.16385 only) that is hard to come by and it causes a rendering error with the Plus1 button rendering.  Here's the code you will need to use to get around this issue:

```
    var gPlusOne = document.createElement('g:plusone'); 
    gPlusOne.setAttribute("size", "medium");
    gPlusOne.setAttribute("annotation", "bubble");
    gPlusOne.setAttribute("width", "120");
    googlePluginDiv[0].appendChild(gPlusOne);
```

Notice I am not using jQuery as jQuery doesn't like the element named `g:plugone`, but it can be rendered with `document.createElement`

Comment: Thanks a lot DMCS! Unfortunately, I could only get this to render in non-IE8 browsers. I haven't tested this outside of my particular case, so I cannot say for sure whether it works or not.

Comment: That above code renders in most all browsers (except really old ones) on Windows and on Mac OS.  It's gone thru extensive 3rd-party QA testing to ensure it does work.  So I'm not sure why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: Thanks DMCS! I'll do some more testing of my own. I'm beginning to think there is some conflicting code in the site I'm working on. By chance, do you have a reference for the rendering error in IE8 (version 8.0.7600.16385) or was this from your own testing? If there is an article, I'd love to peruse it. Either way...thanks for the great help!

Comment: I don't recall an error.  But you can simulated it since you have the IE8 browser that is failing (I don't but the QA team did) and you can make a clean html page with only the plugin on it coded in the normal non-workaround fashion to see.

Comment: That's the exact test that I will do. I've already done it with the standard G+ implementation and am excited to test it with your code (now if only I could get the neverending stream of emails to stop). Thanks again! I'll report my results.

Comment: Sorry for the delay! Thanks again for the help!

Answer (score 0):

For me your solution didn't work (on the specified version of ie8...)
However, it worked using the HTML5 syntax.
I found it here http://chovy.dyndns.org/social2.html.

I reproduce the solution below in case the hosting get down one day :

```
<div class="g-plusone" data-size="standard" data-count="true" [or data-whatever=...]></div>
```

I didn't try to load it dynamically using JS, but I guess it should be OK.

Answer (score 0):

Works perfectly in IE8 and IE9...but not in IE7
 
      
        Share Demo: JQuery Iframe

```
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="gplusID"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var gdiv = document.getElementById('gplusID');
    var gPlusOne = document.createElement('g:plusone'); 
    gPlusOne.setAttribute("size", "medium");
    gPlusOne.setAttribute("annotation", "bubble");
    gPlusOne.setAttribute("width", "120");
    gdiv.appendChild(gPlusOne);
      window.___gcfg = {
        lang: 'en-US'
      };

      (function() {
        var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
        po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
      })();
    </script>  

  </body>

</html>
```